# Let $R$ be a relation on $\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}$ by $(n,m)R(n′,m′)$ iff $nm′=n′m$. Is this relation equivalence?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, equivalence-relations

I proved that it is symmetric and also transitive. But is it a transitive?

*reflexive:*

$(n,m) R (n,m) \Rightarrow  nm = nm$, This is True

*Symmetric:*

$(n,m) R (n',m') \Rightarrow (n',m') R (n,m)$

$nm' = n'm \Rightarrow n'm = m'n $, also True

**BUT**

In prooving transitivity is a problem with zeros.

$(n,m) R (n',m') \wedge (n',m') R (a,b) \Rightarrow (a,b)R(n,m)$

$nm' = n'm \wedge n'b = m'a \Rightarrow nb = ma$

$n = \frac{mn'}{m'}$, $b = \frac{m'a}{n'}$

Now I'm going to substitute $n,b$, so

$\frac{mn'}{m'}\frac{m'a}{n'}=ma \Rightarrow ma = ma$, what is true.

But in the process, I can have problems with zeros in fractions. And I don't know what to do with them.

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Comment: Hint: $(0, 1) \mathrel{R} (0, 0)$ and $(0, 0) \mathrel{R} (1, 0)$.

Comment: "But in the process, I can have problems with zeros in fractions." Excellent! If you're beginning to suspect that you're trying to prove something that's not true, that's precisely where you should start looking for counterexamples. Maybe you'll find some. Maybe you'll stumble upon a proof that covers that special case separately. Either way, it's a win!